# Get time data was submitted from Yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, yfinance

I am working on a project using the Yfinance module to get information from the stock market. My problem is, I need the date/time that the data was submitted, and I don't know how to access it. There is nothing about this that I can find on the documentation, but i know it is there because when i run:

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers='UBER', period='5d', interval='5m')
print(data["Close"])
```

it outputs:

```
Datetime
2021-07-13 09:30:00-04:00    48.349998
2021-07-13 09:35:00-04:00    48.099998
2021-07-13 09:40:00-04:00    47.965000
2021-07-13 09:45:00-04:00    48.021500
2021-07-13 09:50:00-04:00    48.040001
```

The Datetime and the corresponding data. Does anyone know how to access the datetime and store it as a variable?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the index of the DataFrame? `data.index`?

Comment: Yes thats it, Thanky You!

Answer (score 1):

you can store the datetime data in a list

```
from os import pardir
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers='UBER', period='5d', interval='5m')

stored_datetime = data.index
print(stored_datetime)
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-07-16 09:30:00-04:00', '2021-07-16 09:35:00-04:00',
               '2021-07-16 09:40:00-04:00', '2021-07-16 09:45:00-04:00',
               '2021-07-16 09:50:00-04:00', '2021-07-16 09:55:00-04:00',
               '2021-07-16 10:00:00-04:00', '2021-07-16 10:05:00-04:00',
               '2021-07-16 10:10:00-04:00', '2021-07-16 10:15:00-04:00',
               ...
               '2021-07-22 09:30:00-04:00', '2021-07-22 09:35:00-04:00',
               '2021-07-22 09:40:00-04:00', '2021-07-22 09:45:00-04:00',
               '2021-07-22 09:50:00-04:00', '2021-07-22 09:55:00-04:00',
               '2021-07-22 10:00:00-04:00', '2021-07-22 10:05:00-04:00',
               '2021-07-22 10:10:00-04:00', '2021-07-22 10:13:05-04:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', name='Datetime', length=322, freq=None)
```

you can also find datetime for specific row using the row index, data.index[row_number]

```
print(data.index[0])
```

Output:

```
2021-07-16 09:30:00-04:00
```